# Regex for getting domain of a URL Excel VB

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I have an excel file with urls of type
http://test.example.com/anything...

i want to make it
http://test.example.com

does someone know the regex i should use ? (i got a macro in VB for the replace, i just need the regex)

thanks

```
Public Function SearchNReplace1(Pattern1 As String, _
   Pattern2 As String, Replacestring As String, _
   TestString As String)
   Dim reg As New RegExp

   reg.IgnoreCase = True
   reg.MultiLine = False
   reg.Pattern = Pattern1
   If reg.Test(TestString) Then
     reg.Pattern = Pattern2
     SearchNReplace1 = reg.Replace(TestString, Replacestring)
   Else
     SearchNReplace1 = TestString
   End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from: `([a-z]+://[a-z0-9.-]+)[^ ]*` to: `\1`

This will eat enything after the domain name until encountees a space or end of string. Please give more details if this one does not suit you.

If you need ipv6 addresses as hosts you have to allow `[]:` character too:

from: `([a-z]+://[a-z0-9.\[\]:-]+)[^ ]*` to: `\1`

Comment: thanks but it did not work for me. maybe the problem is the script i use, i added it to the post. i have used =SearchNReplace1("([a-z]+://[a-z0-9.-]+)([^ ])*","$1",A2) to activate it and it returned error.

Comment: also, all of the links start with http:// and i can assume they are legal links so i dont need to check it

Comment: The backreference is `\1` instead of the original one. It would help if you wrote any error messages you get.

Comment: vbence actually it worked now with the $1, the problem was in the script, i switched it with a different one i found online. Thanks !!

Comment: I'm glad. MSDN uses backslash for *backreferences* though: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx

Comment: This does not handle IPv6 host names (which use square brackets and colons (e.g. `http://[2001:db8::7]/c=GB?objectClass?one`). Also, the regex should anchor to the start and end of the string (the above regex is not efficient). RFC-3986 already spells out the precise regex you need. (See my answer.)

Comment: Nice, but somehow I don't think it is more efficient at all :) I added another regex which handles ipv6 as well.

Comment: Regarding the efficiency comment, I was wrong and you were right. Please accept my apology! (However, I always get nervous when I see two adjacent sub-expressions, each having an unlimited quantifier and the ability to match the same text; i.e. `[a-z0-9.-]+[^ ]*`. Without end anchors, your regex is quite efficient.)

Comment: However, while looking into this, I did discover a different problem with your solution. Without end anchors, it incorrectly matches a false-`scheme://host` appearing in the fragment or query of a "host-less" URL, e.g. consider this valid URL: `#fragment.with.http://not.a.host`. In this case the correctly captured `scheme://host` should be the empty string.

Comment: Yes, there can be more restricitve solutions, and it makes a realy big difference whether we assume or not that the raw material are valid, absolute URLs. With the `[^ ]*` I just wanted to stay on the safe side, who knows if there is any other content in the cells besides the URLs.

Answer (score 0):

[RFC-3986 Appendix B.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-B) gives us this regex for decomposing a generic URI:

```
^(([^:/?#]+):)?(//([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*)(\?([^#]*))?(#(.*))?
```

Since you are interested in plucking out everything up to the path, here is an equivalent regex which should work quite nicely (in PHP syntax to allow comments):

```php
$re = '%# Match URI and capture scheme and path in $1.
^                  # Anchor to beginning of string.
(                  # $1: Everything up to path.
  (?: [^:/?#]+:)?  # Optional scheme.
  (?://[^/?#]* )?  # Optional authority.
)                  # End $1: Everything up to path.
        [^?#]*     # Required path.
(?:\?    [^#]* )?  # Optional query.
(?:\#       .* )?  # Optional fragment.
$                  # Anchor to end of string.
%x';
```

And here is the exact same regex, in short form, that should work in VB:

```vb
myRegExp.Pattern = "^((?:[^:/?#]+:)?(?://[^/?#]*)?)[^?#]*(?:\?[^#]*)?(?:#.*)?$"
```

This regex does not validate the URI, it just decomposes it into its various components, and pluck out the part you need into capture group 1. Note that every component but the path is optional (and the path, itself, may be empty). In other words, an empty string is a valid URI!

Comment: p.s. If you are looking for a regex to actually _validate_ a URL, check out my (work in progress) article: "[Regular Expression URI Validation](http://jmrware.com/articles/2009/uri_regexp/URI_regex.html)"